# Retrieve Values and Text from HTML Select (drop-down) Element with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, html-select

To test our application I need to check dropdowns (Select elements) `options` against a reference picklist model in an Excel workbook. We need to check both `Text`, which appears on the page and is selected by the user, and `Value`, which is returned to the application.

Example:

```
<select title="Do you have the right to work in Australia? Required
    <option value="" selected="">No Selection</option>
    <option value="4846">No</option>
    <option value="4845">Yes</option>
</select>
```

The values are sent to other systems, so they must be accurate. So we want to check them against a reference WorkBook held in Excel. It's the "values" returned to the application on the `SelectElement` object that I'm having trouble with.

```
IWebElement pickList = session.FindFieldByLabelText(pickListLabel, tagName: "select");
var selectElement = new SelectElement(pickList);
foreach (var option in selectElement.Options)
            { ... }
```

...what? `option.Text` is available but in the debugger and elsewhere I can't find the `.Value`. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `IWebElement` value, or any other, attribute you need to use `GetAttribute()` method

```
foreach (var option in selectElement.Options)
{
    string value = option.GetAttribute("value");
}
```